# How to connect a script?

Tags: asp.net-core

If I understand correctly, then when going to the page 
`https://localhost:44389/Page1/Index`, the text should move ...

I follow the link, but nothing happens. ...
I see a page with the text `test`.
The text does not move.

**Code** "ScriptTest.js", "ScriptJS.js".

```
var divxPos = 0;
window.onload = function () {
    this.runCode()
} 
function runCode() {
    var test = document.getElementById("");
    test.style.left = divxPos++ + 'px'; 
    setTimeout(() => runCode(), 50);
}
```

**Code** `\Page1\Index.cshtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>    
    <script src ="~/ScriptJS.js"> </script>
    @*<script src ="~/JS/ScriptTest.js"> </script>*@

</head>
<body>
    <p id ="testElement"  style="position:absolute">test</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;


namespace WebAppCore
{
    public class Startup
    {

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

        }
    }
}
```

**Code Page1Controller.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebAppCore.Controllers
{
    public class Page1Controller : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


    }
}
```

**Project structure**
[image: **Project structure**]

---

### Update-1

1. I changed the code `Startup.cs`.
2. I created the file `ScriptJS2.js`.
3. I am starting a debug.
4. **Result:** the code does not work.
5. I changed the code for the file `ScriptJS2.js`.
6. I launched debug.
7. **Result:** the code does not work.
8. I see in the file `ScriptJS2.js` the code from `step 2`

**Questions.**
 1. How to make the script work?

2. How to make the new code appear in the `ScriptJS2.js` file?

**Code `Startup.cs`**

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

**Code `ScriptJS2.js` (step 2)**

```
var divxPos = 0;
window.onload = function () {
    var test = document.getElementById("testElement");
    test && runCode(test);
}
function runCode(element) {
    element.style.left = divxPos++ + 'px';
    setTimeout(() => runCode(element), 50);
}
```

**Code `ScriptJS2.js` (step 5)**

```
var divxPos = 0;
window.onload = function () {
    this.runCode()
}
function runCode() {
    var test = document.getElementById("testElement");
    test.style.left = divxPos++ + 'px';
    setTimeout(() => runCode(), 50);
}
```

**Picture-1**
[image]

**Picture-2**
[image]

**Picture-3**
[image]

---

### Update-2

**Console**
***1.*** The connection used to load resources from https://localhost:44389 used TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1, which are deprecated and will be disabled in the future. Once disabled, users will be prevented from loading these resources. The server should enable TLS 1.2 or later. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5654791610957824 for more information.
2:44389/favicon.ico:1
**2.** Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
**3.** DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map
**4.** DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.postload.js.map

**Picture-1**
[image]

---

### Update 3

I created an ASP.NET Core Visual Studio MVC template application.

The code is working.
The text `test` moves around the page.

But!
I want to get an application in which there is nothing superfluous.
I want the application to have only:
  - controller, Index.cshtml, ScriptJS2.js

**Question.**
1. What extra files, folders can I delete from the application that I created in `Update-3`?

**Picture-1**
[image]

**Picture-2**
[image]

Comment: On your js document.getElementById(""); should be document.getElementById("testElement");

Comment: @ZoiloReyes see `Update-1`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `var test = document.getElementById("testElement")` instead.

Besides, the most important thing is that static file middleware  is required to be placed before the endpoint routing middleware, change your startup.cs to

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

    }
```

Comment: see `Update-1`.
I changed the code `Startup.cs`.
I created the file `ScriptJS2.js`.

Comment: @koverflow it [works well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAsTZ.gif)   when i use your code.I see you have 2 errors in F12 console tab which may results in the failure,try to deal with the error firstly

Comment: @ Xing Zou see `Update-2`

Comment: @koverflow It is strange.Could you create a brand new mvc project to test again?

Comment: ASP.NET Core Visual Studio MVC Template?

Comment: @koverflow Yes, I create a new asp.net core mvc template project and it also works...

Comment: see `Update-3`. Comment.

Comment: @koverflow If you could work in mvc, all uncessary  files you could remove , see my project structure https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxPPg.png